# a good way of sharing data between modules using C

Tags: c, modularity

There are two C modules: A and B. They are indepentent from each other.

What is the best way to interchange data between them, if I want to keep them as much independent as possible?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "module" and include any code that you have written that would make the question more clear.

Comment: When you say "module", what do you mean by that? Functions? Translation units? Programs? Shared libraries? Something else?

Comment: What kind of data? What do you mean by "module"?

Comment: Also "*independent*" in terms of what, please?

Comment: I think your question isn't well formulated. The title is about _sharing_ data and in the body you are writing about _interchanging_ them between modules. It isn't the same. Please specify if you want to share data (read and modify them) or interchange data (send data and get result)?

Comment: See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @user4709436 I make you an example for an integer. Declare in the module b.c a global static integer that represent the data you want exchange: static int data; . Then create in the module b.c the function int getdata(void) {return data;} and the function void setdata(int val) {data=val;}. With the correct b.h file you will obtain the module a.c (or what module you want) will be permitted to access the variable data using the function setdata() and getdata() that are in the b.c module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll indicate you how to manage an integer, that is very simple! ... :)

An example may be the following. We have three files: a.c, b.c and b.h

The file a.c will manage an integer that is globally and statically  allocated (statically to hide the variable to other C modules) by the b.c module that exposes the functions to manage that integer.

The file b.h contains the declaration of the functions the module b.c exposes.

The file a.c is:

```
#include "b.h"

int main(void)
{
    setdata(8);
    printf("%d\n",getdata());
    return 0;
}
```

The file b.c may be:

```
#include "b.h"

static int data; /* Here static means data is hidden to other C modules */

int getdata(void)
{
    return data;
}

void setdata(int val)
{
    data=val;
}
```

The file b.h

```
#ifndef B_H__
#define B_H__

void setdata(int);
int getdata(void);

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you implement information hiding by declaring your persistent variables at "static". Outside a function, this means "only visible from this .c file"; inside a function, it means "local to this function, but persistent".

You then communicate between modules only by calling functions, passing values into them and getting return values from them.

Comment: Is better to think that this is the only way to share variables between C modules. But exist also the (worst) way to call it directly declaring it extern into the include file that indicates the function and data the module exposes!